# Pointer and Index in C - What is wrong?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, misra

Update: I got the confirmation that the behaviour is due to a bug in the code checker (see comment to answer #2)

I am trying out a static Code checker and it complains:

Array pointer `sensorConf' is accessed with index [8,8] which may be out of array bounds [0,UNKNOWN]    MISRAC2012-Rule-18.1_d

The Code is:

```
typedef struct
{
    int16_t signalOrig;
} TT;

typedef struct
{
   int iii; // <-- see below: int16_t iii would work without warning!
   uint16_t numCalibPairs; 
  TT calib[5];
} SS;

void Test(const SS* sensorConf);

void Test(const SS* sensorConf)
{
  const int16_t f = sensorConf->calib[0].signalOrig;
  }
```

I had asked:
Why is it saying "Array pointer"? Why does it think that the Index is [8,8]? Is it just a problem of the code checker or is there a problem with my code?

Edit:
The Code checker (C-STAT) gives not only one but 3 rules which all have the meaning that there is an Access out of bounds of an Array.
Now, if I remove the first or second integer in struct SS the warning disappears. It also disappears if I Change "iii" from int (32bit, ARM cortex M4) to int16_t. The warning does not appear if there are only 4 Bytes before the Array in struct SS. Looks like a bug in the checker?

Comment: Please extract a [mcve], as per site guidelines.

Comment: I have made a minimal version now.

Answer (score 1):

The code is safe - the pointer will always be to a signalOrig, as long as AWISIL_MAX_CALIB_PAIRS is greater than zero. Without knowing the text of MISRA rule 18.1c, I can't tell you whether it complies however.

The static checker can't verify compliance with this programmatically. The message is only a warning.

Comment: The rule says: "A pointer to an array is potentially used outside the array bounds."

Comment: It is impossible for calib[0] to be outside the bounds of calib

Comment: I see it is a problem to check existing code, because there are many more warnings. Here the checker has obviously a bug, which took already much time to find. How many other warnings have to be checked, I dont't know.

Answer (score 1):

MISRA-C:2012 18.1 is merely a fundamental one saying that you should never access an array out-of-bounds, or do pointer arithmetic beyond the pointed-at array.

You code does not do this, unless the tool managed to find something in the calling code such as an uninitialized pointer - we can't tell from the code posted.

If the parameter pointed at is definitely an allocated `SS` struct, then the warning is a false positive. `sensorConf` is definitely not an array pointer. It does indeed seem that the IAR MISRA checker is buggy.

Comment: I have forwarded the bug to IAR and they confirmed it. It will be fixed in  EWARM version 8.30.1